# c++: No instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, function, overloading

**highInterestChecking Header:**

```
#ifndef H_highInterestChecking
#define H_highInterestChecking
#include "noservicechargechecking.h"
#include <string>

class highInterestChecking: public noServiceChargeChecking
{
public:
    highInterestChecking(std::string =" ",int = 0, double = 0.00, double = 0.00, double = 0.00);
};
#endif
```

**highInterestChecking cpp:**

```
#include "highInterestChecking.h"
using std::string;

highInterestChecking::highInterestChecking(string name, int acct, double bal, int numCheck, double min, double i)
{
    bankAccount::setAcctOwnersName(name);
    bankAccount::setAcctNum(acct);
    bankAccount::setBalance(bal);
    checkingAccount::setChecks(numCheck);
    noServiceChargeChecking::setMinBalance(min);
    noServiceChargeChecking::setInterestRate(i);
}
```

I have the error "No instance of overloaded function." under the constructor name highInterestChecking in the cpp file not sure what is causing it ive looked at it for a while now can't seem to find an error. maybe someone will help?

Comment: You need variable names. You are assigning values to the type `double` a parameter as if it were a variable in your parameter list.

Comment: @RageD: No, that's fine. He is presenting a parameter with no name, then a default value for that parameter.

Comment: You forgot `int numCheck` parameter in function declaration.

Comment: in the header file it is okay to do that to set default parameters.

Comment: @Axilles: You got it. Should be an answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not only i :) just mark one of others answers below. Be more attentive at future.

Comment: @Axilles: (a) You commented before they were posted (well, Shafik _just_ beat you, but not before I could notice!), and if you knew the answer was already posted then why did you write your comment? Be more attentive in the future, and write answers as _answers_. (b) I am not the OP, so I cannot mark answers as accepted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, i understand. I usually afraid to make a mistake in an answer, so write comments insead of them (to be honest).

Comment: @Axilles: I'm sorry to hear that; that is not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. Be brave and post! If you get downvoted, it's a learning opportunity; in this case, you would have gotten upvoted and perhaps even accepted!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm the shy man. But if StackOverflow need brave people, i will try to become one of them :) thanks for making things clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the header you have:

```
highInterestChecking(std::string =" ",int = 0, double = 0.00, double = 0.00, double = 0.00);
```

Which takes `5` arguments, In the source file you have:

```
 highInterestChecking::highInterestChecking(string name, int acct, double bal, int numCheck, double min, double i)

                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which takes `6` arguments. It seems like `int numCheck` does not match the header signature.

Comment: Thank you lol how did i miss that i swear i counted the parameters guess my eyes are starting to go lol

Comment: @EricOudin that is a sign you have too many parameters. You could consider bundling some of them into a class.

Answer (score 2):

You have this constructor in the class declaration:

```
highInterestChecking(std::string =" ",int = 0, double = 0.00, double = 0.00, double = 0.00);
```

and this one in the class definition:

```
highInterestChecking::highInterestChecking(string name, int acct, double bal, int numCheck, double min, double i)
```

The parameter types from both parameter lists must match.

Comment: This is misleading. They don't need to be "the same" _lexically_, though they must describe the same list of parameter types.

Answer (score 2):

```
  highInterestChecking::highInterestChecking(string name, int acct, 
                           double bal, int numCheck, double min, double i)
                                       //^^^
```

does not exist in your class's header file, header file has 5 parameters, but you have 6 in cpp file, parameter type seems mismatched,